# parsing JSON array of JSON objects using Jackson throws JSON Mapping Exception, how to fix?

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

This is my JSON :

```
    [
        {
           "_id": "574f1840d21303358a03d78b",
           "name": "Bank One of Kerala",
           "period_from": "2016-03-12T00:00:00.000Z",
           "period_to": "2016-03-12T00:00:00.000Z",
           "status": true,
           "ins": "Get an account at Bank One of Kerala :P",
           "fields": [
               {
                   "field": "Account Number",
                   "key": "acc"
               },
               {
                   "field": "IFSC",
                   "key": "ifsc"
               },
               {
                   "field": "Branch",
                   "key": "branch"
               },
               {
                   "field": "Name",
                   "key": "name"
               },
               {
                   "field": "PAN",
                   "key": "pan"
               }
          ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "574f18e4d21303358a03d78c",
        "name": "Bank Two of India",
        "period_from": "2016-03-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        "period_to": "2016-03-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        "status": true,
        "ins": "Get an account at Bank Two of India",
        "fields": [
            {
                "field": "Account Number",
                "key": "acc"
            },
            {
                "field": "IFSC",
                "key": "ifsc"
            },
            {
                "field": "Branch",
                "key": "branch"
            },
            {
                "field": "Name",
                "key": "name"
            }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is my model class:

**ShreyPojo.class**

```
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "_id",
        "name",
        "period_from",
        "period_to",
        "status",
        "ins",
        "fields"
})
public class ShreyPojo
{
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("period_from")
    private String periodFrom;
    @JsonProperty("period_to")
    private String periodTo;
    @JsonProperty("status")
    private Boolean status;
    @JsonProperty("ins")
    private String ins;
    @JsonProperty("fields")
    private List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The id
     */
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * The _id
     */
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The name
     */
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param name
     * The name
     */
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The periodFrom
     */
    @JsonProperty("period_from")
    public String getPeriodFrom() {
        return periodFrom;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param periodFrom
     * The period_from
     */
    @JsonProperty("period_from")
    public void setPeriodFrom(String periodFrom) {
        this.periodFrom = periodFrom;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The periodTo
     */
    @JsonProperty("period_to")
    public String getPeriodTo() {
        return periodTo;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param periodTo
     * The period_to
     */
    @JsonProperty("period_to")
    public void setPeriodTo(String periodTo) {
        this.periodTo = periodTo;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The status
     */
    @JsonProperty("status")
    public Boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param status
     * The status
     */
    @JsonProperty("status")
    public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The ins
     */
    @JsonProperty("ins")
    public String getIns() {
        return ins;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param ins
     * The ins
     */
    @JsonProperty("ins")
    public void setIns(String ins) {
        this.ins = ins;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The fields
     */
    @JsonProperty("fields")
    public List<Field> getFields() {
        return fields;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param fields
     * The fields
     */
    @JsonProperty("fields")
    public void setFields(List<Field> fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

**Field.class**

```
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "field",
        "key"
})

    public class Field
    {

        @JsonProperty("field")
        private String field;
        @JsonProperty("key")
        private String key;
        @JsonIgnore
        private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        /**
         *
         * @return
         * The field
         */
        @JsonProperty("field")
        public String getField() {
            return field;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param field
         * The field
         */
        @JsonProperty("field")
        public void setField(String field) {
            this.field = field;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         * The key
         */
        @JsonProperty("key")
        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param key
         * The key
         */
        @JsonProperty("key")
        public void setKey(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        @JsonAnyGetter
        public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
            return this.additionalProperties;
        }

        @JsonAnySetter
        public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
            this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
        }
    }
```

And, now when I try to parse the JSON,

```
 ShreyPojo obj = mapper.readValue(res,ShreyPojo.class); //res is the JSON string
 Log.w("JACKSON",""+obj.getName());
```

I get the exception :

```
    D/OkHttp: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.shreybank.shrey.pojo.ShreyPojo out of START_ARRAY token
D/OkHttp:  at [Source: [{"_id":"574f1840d21303358a03d78b","name":"Bank One of Kerala","period_from":"2016-03-12T00:00:00.000Z","period_to":"2016-03-12T00:00:00.000Z","status":true,"ins":"Get an account at Bank One of Kerala :P","fields":[{"field":"Account Number","key":"acc"},{"field":"IFSC","key":"ifsc"},{"field":"Branch","key":"branch"},{"field":"Name","key":"name"},{"field":"PAN","key":"pan"}]},{"_id":"574f18e4d21303358a03d78c","name":"Bank Two of India","period_from":"2016-03-12T00:00:00.000Z","period_to":"2016-03-12T00:00:00.000Z","status":true,"ins":"Get an account at Bank Two of India","fields":[{"field":"Account Number","key":"acc"},{"field":"IFSC","key":"ifsc"},{"field":"Branch","key":"branch"},{"field":"Name","key":"name"}]}]; line: 1, column: 1]
D/OkHttp:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:873)
D/OkHttp:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:869)
D/OkHttp:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1293)
D/OkHttp:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
D/OkHttp:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:135)
D/OkHttp:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789)
D/OkHttp:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2779)
D/OkHttp:     at com.shreybank.shrey.activities.BankDetailsActivity$1.onResponse(BankDetailsActivity.java:77)
D/OkHttp:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:133)
D/OkHttp:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
D/OkHttp:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
D/OkHttp:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
D/OkHttp:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Since similar questions exist, I tried them in case I made a common mistake, since this one is not same, how to fix this?

Comment: Shaheen, res is `JSONArray of JSONObject's`, so you need to first get all JSONObject's from it in List then iterate it

Comment: Like `List<ShreyPojo> listShreyPojo = objectMapper.readValue(res, new TypeReference<List<ShreyPojo>>() {});
`

Comment: aah :D , seems like I made a blunder

Comment: Why not post it as an answer, to end the question!

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I get crash now :/ ` java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.shreybank.shrey.pojo.ShreyPojo`

Comment: Please show update logs and code if still facing same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113705/discussion-between-shaheen-and--k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code.

```
 try {

       JSONArray  jsonArray = new JSONArray(res);
       List<ShreyPojo> pojoList = new ArrayList<>();

       for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
       {
          //JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String jsonObject = jsonArray.getString(i);

          ShreyPojo obj = mapper.readValue(jsonObject,ShreyPojo.class); 

           pojoList.add(obj);
       }

   // Use ShreyPojo objects as per requirement

 } catch (Exception e)
 {
    Log.w("Exception = ","" + e.toString());
 }
```

Comment: ShreyPojo obj = mapper.readValue(jsonObject,ShreyPojo.class);

Comment: Getting error in this line : cannot resolve method 'readValue(org.json.JSONObject,java.lang.Class<ShreyPojo>)'

Comment: Thanks for helping out!

Comment: anytime enjoy your coding